# C++ Builder 2010, add folder to project

Tags: directory, addition, c++builder, c++builder-2010

I am sorry for this "beginner" question, but I am not able add directory with the existing source code to the new project created in C++ Builder 2010 (that I am using very rarely).

I tryied to drag the folder to the project manager. The question "Would you like to add selected files to project" is displayed and and after confirmation nothing has been done...

I am not able to force C++ Builder for adding whole folders ( the files only...).

Comment: I'm not sure you can. After all, Builder works only with c++ and a few other file types, and a folder can contain anything. But you can always open "add file" dialog and select all files and it will add them if it can.

Comment: But the project folder contains more than 200 subfolders :-(. I will spent all evening doing it one by one file ...

Comment: I don't think Builder can recurse in to subfolders. It's actually pretty fragile IDE, so it might not even handle a lot of files.

Comment: Here is an idea, don't know if it works. Do a search in windows explorer for all file types you want to add. Then select them all and drag to IDE.

Comment: please, answer your question, or make @Johnas do it, and mark it as the solution...

Comment: Gene's answer is the way to go. In my case, with RAD Studio 10.3 it's worse: If you directly drag'n drop a folder containing subfolders, It only imports a few files. It does not inform you that the others were not processed. With Gene's procedure it imports everything !